# Can we link web parts inside the Modern Site Pages with exsisting lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, design, pages, modern-pages

I migrated my SharePoint on-premises 2013 team site, to sharepoint online. one of the most interesting features i found in SharePoint online is the Modern site pages. where inside the Modern site pages i can add web parts for Quick Links and images as follow:-

[image]

but is it possible to link those modern web parts with existing Picture libraries and existing links lists. as inside my on-premises sites i already have the following 2 lists:-

1. Links
2. Picture Library

and they already contain data, s**o can i link the modern page's web parts with those 2 list and library**?

**Second question** i have , now inside the modern site pages, when i add for example a Quick Links web part (as shown in the above picture), i have noted that sharepoint did not create a new list to store the links.. so not sure how sharepoint online store the images and links for the modern page's web parts? and will the permission for those web parts be inherited from the modern page permission ?

Answer (score 1):

**Connect the Image Gallery to the existing Library**
[image]

**Connect Quick links to the existing SharePoint list that stores the links**

This is not possible. There is no option for that in the webpart's properties.

**Where do SharePoint framework webparts store properties?**

WP properties are stored in the webpart's property bag, not in the list. All SharePoint property bags are stored in the SharePoint database. More info [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/integrate-web-part-properties-with-sharepoint).

**Can you programmatically populate the properties in the Quick links webpart based on your old SharePoint 2013 Links list?**

I'm sure you can, if you find a way to modify SPFx's properties using PowerShell or CSOM. It deserves a separate question here.

Comment: regarding linking the "Image gallery" with exsisting picture library, now when i edit my "image gallery" inside my modern site page, i did not get the options under "image options" i only get the options under "layout".. so do u know what could be the problem?

Comment: second point, for the WP inside modern pages, i am not asking about where the WP properties are being stored, i am asking where the data (the images and/or the links) are being stored? For example, i thought if i add "Image Gallery" inside a modern page's WP, then SP will create picture library behind the scenes to store the pictures.but seems this is not the case.

Comment: It is possible that I've got a newer version of SharePoint Online. My farm has "early release" option enabled. Otherwise - I don't really know.